# When I introduce a background color to my about section the image after disappears (image: after is the yellow border)

Tags: html, css

When I introduce a background color of black the image after disappears, The image after is the yellow border with a z index of -1 appearing behind the image. I need the section to have a background image of black and also for the image after to appear.

```css
    
  

      #about .about {
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
      text-align: center;
      max-width: 1500px;
      margin: o auto;
      padding: 100px 20px;
      }
      #about .col-left {
      width: 250px;
      height: 360px;
      }
      #about .col-right {
      width: 100%;
      }
      #about .col-right h2 {
      font-size: 2.5rem;
      font-weight: 500;
      letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      color: yellow;
      }
      #about .col-right p {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      color: white;
      }
      #about .col-left {
       position: relative;
      }
      #about .col-left .img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 10px solid black;
      }
      #about .col-left .img::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: -33px;
      top: 19px;
      height: 98%;
      width: 98%;
     border: 10px solid yellow;
     z-index: -1;
     }
```

```html
    <section id="about">
      <div class="about container">
        <div class="col-left">
          <div class="img">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x360" alt="img" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-right">
          <h1 class="section-title">ABOUT US</h1>
          <h2>What we do</h2>
          <p>
            Today is the day.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Could you share the relevant CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `z-index` of your `img:after` set to `-1` the `<section>` will be in front of the `img:after` so set your `z-index` of your `<section>` to `-2` that will make it visible.

As shown in the snippet below the yellow border is now in front of the black background. It doesn't seem like everything is aligned properly but from your given CSS I can't make up where what should go. I can improve it if you give more detail about how it should be aligned.

```css
#about {
   position:absolute;
   background:black;
   z-index:-2;
}

#about .about {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 100px 20px;
}

#about .col-left {
  width: 250px;
  height: 360px;
}

#about .col-right {
  width: 100%;
}

#about .col-right h2 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: yellow;
}

#about .col-right p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
}

#about .col-left {
  position: relative;
}

#about .col-left .img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

#about .col-left .img::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -33px;
  top: 19px;
  height: 98%;
  width: 98%;
  border: 10px solid yellow;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
  <div class="about container">
    <div class="col-left">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x360" alt="img" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-right">
      <h1 class="section-title">ABOUT US</h1>
      <h2>What we do</h2>
      <p>
        Today is the day.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct thanks.

Comment: Everything I do on my homepage is affecting this particular section, what could be the problem? I have an animation on my home page but its also applying here.

Comment: I can only guess without seeing the other html/css code. Maybe it's because the ```position:absolute``` you can try to change it to ```position:relative``` https://leannezhang.medium.com/difference-between-css-position-absolute-versus-relative-35f064384c6

Answer (score 0):

Thats what I get when I add a background-color like that:

```
#about .col-left .img {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

[image]

But I'm really not sure how it should look like. Maybe you could upload a picture of what you want to achieve?

If you want a yellow shadow you need to postion the image, otherwise your pos absolute on the yellow border doesn't work

```
#about .col-left .img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 10px solid black;
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
}
#about .col-left .img::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: 8px;
    height: 98%;
    width: 98%;
    border: 10px solid yellow;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[image]

In the end there is just one question: why dont you use [box-shadows](https://cssgenerator.org/box-shadow-css-generator.html), instead of the :after?

```
#about .col-left .img {
     box-shadow: -17px 18px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,0,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -17px 18px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,0,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: -17px 18px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,0,1);
 }
```